# Strange results from Observable.concat(observable,observable)

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

A while a go, I read about RxJava concat and decided to test my understanding. But I've encountered some behavior that I don't quite understand.

The problem is that when I concat two observables I get different behaviours depending on the order in which i pass them to Observable.concat()

```
val ob1 = createObservableSomehow()

val ob2 = createObservableSomehow()

Observable.concat(ob1,ob2).subscribe(::println) //only prints emissions of ob1


Observable.concat(ob2,ob1).subscribe(...) //concats all emissions correctly
```

See the attached screenshot to see how am creating the two observables.
[image: This screenshot shows how am creating the observables]

Comment: what exactly you want to know?

Comment: `concat` requires its sources to complete and only then will it switch to the next one.

Comment: Please don't use images for code, it's impossible for people with screen readers or restrictive corporate proxies to read what you have to say.

Comment: @Todd that's true, was having hard time using the inline code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`concat()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#concat-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-) will wait for the first stream to complete only then it will start emitting items from second stream.

In your case you have **not** declared, that the first observable has completed its emission, so [`concat()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#concat-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-) assumes there are still emissions to come, because no terminal event has ever been dispatched.

As soon as you execute `it.onComplete()` inside your first stream you will see the output you expect.

Comment: Good answer, where in the documentation does it says that ?

Comment: @Remario, "Returns an Observable that emits the items emitted by two ObservableSources, one after the other, without interleaving them". In this context "emits one observable after another" assumes, that the first one should be completed, otherwise there is no way for the `concat` to understand whether there are some items to come or no. Also, see in the [rx marble](https://raw.github.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/concat.png) how terminal event (`|`) is being emitted from first stream.

Comment: Thanks i , reactive programming is pretty abstract at times, it always makes me ponder

Answer (score 1):

You need to call onComplete() after last onNext() for first Observable